# Are Tabletop Roleplay Games a sin?

Tags: sin, games-toys

*I'm an atheist (agnostic with a Christian background) Game master.*

One of my Jewish friend showed interested in one of my roleplay campaign, while I'd be very happy to introduce him to the game, I have a few concerns :

My campaign is set in a pretty classical heroic fantasy universe. As you could expect from such a world, magic (both divine and profane), demons, angels and gods can appear rather easily (and often). There is also all the other standard strange creatures like orcs, goblins and ghosts.

Player Characters may also get missions where they have to do rather sinful things like killing, stealing and all that jazz. (Even if our current characters are good, forgiving and lawful most of the time.)

I was wondering if it would be considered a sin to play (and act) as such a character, per jewish tradition.

If it is, is there any kind of roleplay game (or setting) that would be better suited for my friend ?

If it is not, is there any lines I should not cross ?

Thank you for any advice.

*PS : I'd like to note that, outside of the game, me and my other players are pretty chill, no drinking during the game, no swearing and we are very tolerant, so I do not think that our company is a problem in itself.*

*PS+ : I should also note that my friend's parent are rather... "strict". I'm afraid he would get punished if his parent discovered he is being sinful. (whether he really is sinning or they just think he is.)*

Comment: Funny... I've played DnD for years and never once thought of this question... I'm not even sure I've heard it discussed in Jewish circles, though I know it used to be a hot topic in Christian ones...

Comment: (And ignoring the fact that he should rather be spending his time learning Torah... after taking short breaks as needed for his sanity and concentration. Breaks that won't distract him for hours.)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for bringing this interesting question here.  Your sensitivity to your players is commendable.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Considering how much time the average person spends on "frivolous" activities (including otherwise religious individuals), spending time engaged in collaborative story telling and camaraderie isn't something to sneer at...

Comment: http://dinonline.org/2017/07/14/avodah-zarah-related-game/ This might be of some use.

Comment: Léon Donnet-Monay, I like the quote in your "About Me" section on your profile. ;P

Comment: I've no source for this at the moment, but I understand some Jews will, for religion-based moral (not strict thou-shalt-not) reasons, refrain and/or have their kids refrain from playing games that include physical fighting (e.g. swordfighting with a Nerf sword). I think this is because it's thought to desensitize the person to actual violence. I don't know whether the same is true of tabletop games; I've never heard, for example, any objection to Risk or Stratego, but maybe such exists.